# Windows 10 Upgrade Fails - 8007002C-4000D

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

An annoying issue - I've done a lot of research into this issue, and the best thread I've found is over at [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3f2ytj/windows_10_error_0x8007002c_0x4000d_the/ctllkc6]).

I've tried unplugging every USB peripheral except Keyboard/Mouse, uninstalling Microsoft Security Essentials, doing it from a Clean Boot and disabling all network adapters - and it still fails at about 50% of configuring settings.

If anyone's got anymore advice, that'd be great.

I'm running a SSD with a 1TB Hard Disk.

UPDATE (27/09/2015): I've still had no success with this upgrade, even after trying the ISO upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows 10 Upgrade Error 8007002C-4000D

> **0x8007002C-0x4000D**
>
> Attempt the same solutions used for error code 0xC1900101-0x4000D

...

> **0xC1900101-0x4000D**
>
> > The installation failed in the SECOND_BOOT phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation
>
> - Disable (preferrably uninstall) your Antivirus utility before attempting the upgrade.
> - Disable General USB Devices (example - Smart Card Reader).
> - Do a clean boot and try again.
> - If you are upgrading using the .ISO file, disconnect from the Internet during setup, if you are connected by LAN (Ethernet) or
>     Wi-Fi, disable both and attempt setup again.
> - If you are updating through Windows Update, when the download reaches 100% disconnect from the Internet LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi and
>     proceed with the installation.
> - If that does not work, try using the .ISO file to upgrade if possible.
> - If you are connected to a domain, switch to a local account
> - If you have any external devices attached to the machine, disconnect them (example, USB keys, external hard disk, printers,
>     non-essential devices).
>
> [How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10
>   ISO file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43)
>
> [How to download official Windows 10 ISO files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326)

Source [How to: Troubleshoot common Setup and Stop Errors during Windows 10 Installation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-troubleshoot-common-setup-and-stop-errors/324d5a5f-d658-456c-bb82-b1201f735683)

Comment: I couldn't find an upgrade ISO anywhere, but apart from that I've done all the steps.

Comment: @Tjcrazy [How to download official Windows 10 ISO files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326) will give you a Windows 10 ISO. The ISO can be used to first upgrade (see  [How to: upgrade from previous versions of Windows using Windows 10 ISO file](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43)) and then later perform a clean install if you want.

Comment: @Tjcrazy Both links are already in the answer :/

Comment: just tried from the ISO upgrade, and again it failed with the same error code

Comment: @Tjcrazy Did you "disconnect from the Internet during setup, if you are connected by LAN (Ethernet) or Wi-Fi, disable both and attempt setup again." as instructed?

Comment: yes - disabled all network adapters

Comment: This issue is still present in the 1909 update. Even after having no PCIe cards, onboard ethernet and audio disabled, only mouse and keyboard hooked on USB, clean boot with all non-Microsoft services disabled, with no antivirus, no domain, and upgrading from USB, the update stalls at 87% and upon restarting shows the error from the title.