# Windows update error: 0xc1900101 on upgrading to windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I was trying to upgrade windows 10 to 11 preview build by windows update and then while installing update(after restarting), my system displays 'undoing changes made to your system...' and after awhile it reverts back to windows 10 itself. After that going to system updates, I get error code: 0xc1900101.  My system meets the system requirements and TPM(2.0) is enabled.

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
RAM: 16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
System type: 6.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
```

Happy to provide more info. Thanks :D

Comment: I wonder if windows 11 has [setupdiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag) - Its what I'd use with windows 10

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think it does :(

Comment: Try downloading it from there and running it. For science :)

Comment: @CoolCloud - Have you run the tool?  We cannot help you unless you provide log files. Be sure Compatability Mode is disabled and Secure Boot is enabled.  Additionally, if you have additional drives connected to your system, you should try disconnecting them.  If all that fails, then run DISM and SFC, to verify you have no system corruption.  `0xc1900101` is not unique to Windows 11, there are many reasons, you would get that error.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1113521/) and [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1449011/) have some of those explanations.  Feel free to [edit] your question and include the required information we need to answer your question.  If you were wondering [This](https://superuser.com/questions/977115/windows-10-upgrade-fails-8007002c-4000d/977166#977166) would be what SetupDiag would have given you.  Be sure you have at least 64 GB free

Comment: Okay I will try all these and get back :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did use it now, but the 'log' file is empty.

Comment: 0xc1900101 is usually a driver problem

Comment: @Moab Hmmmm I updated my BIOS but the same issue persists